# Как сделать проверку языка ввода при вводе пароля?

Tags: c#, wpf

Хочу запретить ввод отличных от латинских символов при вводе логина и пароля при регистрации.

Делаю регистрацию в WPF и хочу предупреждать пользователя о том, что ввод на других языках запрещен.

Comment: Зачем такое странное условие? Вы, надеюсь, не собираетесь хранить пароль в открытом виде в базе?

Comment: Ввод пользователя можно проверить в KeyPress например при помощи регулярки: [a-zA-Z]* (допилить нужными разрешенными символами) и отреагировать нужным вам способом.

Comment: Или же просто проверять, чтобы код каждого символа соответствовал нужному условию (больше-равно А, меньше равно Z) && (больше-равно а, меньше-равно z).

Comment: @Roman Kotenko: `||`?

Answer (score 4):

Я бы сделал бы вот так

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {    
     if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, "^[a-zA-Z]") && textBox1.TextLength!=0) {
          MessageBox.Show("Ввод возможен только на латинице");
          textBox1.Text.Remove(textBox1.Text.Length - 1);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот рабочий код для проекта WinForm.
Думаю, для wpf вы переделаете без труда. Код рабочий.

```
private void FIOTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      bool BadSymbolsInside = false;
      for (int i = 0; i < FIOTextBox.Text.Length; i++)
      {
        if (!((FIOTextBox.Text[i] > 'A' && FIOTextBox.Text[i] < 'Z') ||
            (FIOTextBox.Text[i] > 'a' && FIOTextBox.Text[i] < 'z') ||
          //Любые другие диапазоны числе по вашему вкусу ||
            (FIOTextBox.Text[i] > '0' && FIOTextBox.Text[i] < '9')))
        {
          BadSymbolsInside = true;
        }
      }
      if (BadSymbolsInside)
      {
        MessageBox.Show("Вы используете недопустимые символы \nДля логина можно использовать только латинские буквы и цифры");
        FIOTextBox.Text = "";
      }
    }
```

Comment: за что минусы то?

Comment: Похоже за го*нокод.

Comment: @Breaker да, с кодом проблемы, но он, по-крайне мере, знает как решить эту проблему:)